# How to manually call json objects using its own object?

Tags: node.js, json

Say I have the following json files:

```
const obj1 = {
   en: {
      user: {
          name: "John"
      }
   },
   language: "en"
}
```

```
const obj2 = {
   ru: {
      user: {
          name: "Vladimir"
      }
   },
   language: "ru"
}
```

To retrieve these objects with NODE I will use the following code:

```
let en_name = obj1.en.user.name; //returns John
let ru_name = obj2.ru.user.name; //returns Vladimir
```

Is it possible to use the object `language`, and call the `user.name` based on the language? maybe something like this, which doesn't work:

```
let lang = obj.language
let anyName = language.user.name;
```

---

UPDATE:

I want to access data.jvProfiles.ANY_LANGUAGE.title as shown in the figure:

[image]

```
console.log(data.preferredLanguage); //Returns "nl"
let title = data.jvProfiles.nl.title; //Ruturns "Database Marketeer"

console.log(data.jvProfiles.data[data.preferredLanguage]); //gives error
console.log(data.jvProfiles.data[data.preferredLanguage].title); //gives same error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'nl' of undefined
```

---

SOLUTION:

```
console.log(data.jvProfiles[data.preferredLanguage].title);
```

Comment: console.log(data.jvProfiles[data.preferredLanguage].title) this should work

Comment: It does indeed. Thanks a lot @Shivam !  :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use square brackets notation to access an object property dynamically:

```js
const obj = {
   en: {
      user: {
          name: "John"
      }
   },
   language: "en"
}

const name = obj[obj.language].user.name

console.log(name)
```

Comment: its my first day using JSON and do not know much! This works great with the given example but when I tried with my actual code it doesn't work as it is more complicated. The question has been updated